# if statement to activate a function after a time period (solidity)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, evm

I want the following function to activate after 6 mins(360 secs) of contract deployment because my task requires a withdrawal lock. should I put  `if (block.timestamp > 360)` before the function or inside the function just before the remaining code?

```
 function withdraw(uint256 amount) external updateReward(msg.sender) nonReentrant {
        if (block.timestamp > 360) {
        s_totalSupply -= amount;
        s_balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        emit WithdrewStake(msg.sender, amount);
        // transfer: send tokens from contract back to msg.sender.
        bool success = s_stakingToken.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        if (!success) {
            revert TransferFailed(); // revert resets everything done in a failed transaction.
        }}
    }
```

But I'm not even sure if `if (block.timestamp > 360)` is the right code for this case.

Comment: I tested it on remix. It doesnt look like it does what you want. Ill try figure it out with you.

Comment: It would be nice to get an upvote for my answer if you think it is suffice. Was one of my first contributions to stackoverflow :) thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out for you my brother:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
import "hardhat/console.sol";
contract TimeTest{
    uint256 public initialTime;
    constructor () public{
        initialTime = block.timestamp;
    }
    function withdraw() public {
        uint256 nowTime = block.timestamp-initialTime; // time between deployment of contract and now.
        console.log(nowTime);
        if (nowTime > 60) {
            console.log("Time is up");
        }
    }

}
```

The reason why you have to do that is because block.timestamp doesnt represent the time since the contract was deployed, but the time since the unix epoch. The name of the variable is a little misleading.

You can find more info here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/units-and-global-variables.html

Or here:https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/12/writing-a-contract-that-handles-time/ (just know that "now" doesnt exist anymore since version 0.0.7. "now" was equivalent to "block.timestamp". But the tutorial is still valid if you replace "now" with "block.timestamp".